# How to achive multiprocessing with time constraint in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two functions that need to be run parallel using scheduler. I implemented with multiprocessing but one process blocks other process. How to achieve such functionality where lets say one function runs every 5 minutes and performs some task while other functions also performs some task every 2 minutes? Here both functions are different.

I have used scheduler to run both functions. But it blocks other function until its finished.

For example:

```
    def count1():
         now = datetime.now()
         start_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
         time.sleep(5)
         datetime.now()
         end_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    def count2():
         now = datetime.now()
         start_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
         time.sleep(5)
         datetime.now()
         end_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        schedule.every(5).seconds.do(count1)
        schedule.every(15).seconds.do(count2)
        while True:
            # Checks whether a scheduled task
            # is pending to run or not
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

I want to run both functions parallel without blocking each other. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Your question should include a small runnable example illustrating the problem.

Comment: @FMc edited similar code

Comment: That's better, but it's still not runnable (you are missing 3 needed imports), and it could use some `print()` statements or something to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package, which is described in the first paragraph of its documentation as an **in-process scheduler** – in other words, it won't give you parallelism. The documentation also includes an FAQ entry on [running jobs in parallel](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-execute-jobs-in-parallel).

Bottom line: if you want parallelism, you'll need to set up your own threads or processes, or find a different scheduling package that does that stuff.